# Determine a possible quartic polynomial equation such that $f(x) > 0$ for $-4 < x < -2$ and $3 < x < 7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials, quartics

In typical high school fashion, nowhere in the curriculum was there a question about creating a polynomial equation. Yet here it is in the exam practice questions. Little help please?

Comment: Well, what has to happen if a polynomial changes sign at, say $x = 3$?

Comment: Or, since the question is quite ambiguous, $f(x)=x^{4}+1$

Answer (score 2):

A polynomial will change sign at the roots.

If the roots are $-2,-4, 3, 7$ then $P(x) = a(x+2)(x+4)(x-3)(x-7)$ and for $x\le 3$ we have $x+2,x+4, x-3, x-7 < 0$ and $P(x) \le 0$ so $a < 0$ and for $-2 < x < -4$ we have $(x+2) > 0, x+4 < 0, x-3< 0, x-7 < 0$ so $a < 0$ means $P(x) > 0$ and so on.

SO $P(x) = -(x+4)(x+2)(x-3)(x-7)$ is one possible solution.

But the question never said $f(x) \le 0$ *outside* the intervals.  So long as the roots (if any) are outside the intervals and there are the right even or odd number of roots between $-2$ and $3$ it will work.

$P(x) = (x+1)x(x-1)(x-2)$ will be acceptable as $x+1,x,x-1, x-2 < 1$ for $-4 < x < -2$ so $P(x) > 0$ there and $x+1,x, x-1, x-2 > 0$ for $3< x< 7$ so $P(x) > 0$ there.

We can even do $P(x) = x^4 + 1$ as that is positive anywhere. (and has no roots).

Comment: Even $x^4$ works.

Comment: Yes.  Even $x^4 -1$ works.

Comment: Sure, but $x^4$ is shorter ;-)

Comment: Well, I stole the comment from Joshua Wang.  I assume his point was that $x^4 +c; c> 0$ is positive *everywhere* so we don't have to think or do *anything*.  $x^4$ is not positive everywhere.  So we still have to think.   But the only point it isn't positive won't matter as it isn't in our intervals. So we don't have to think very hard.

Comment: $x^4$ has a quadruple root at $x =0$ and $x^4-1$ has a double roots at $x = 1$ and $x=-1$... outside our interval so that $P(x) < 0$ for $-1 < x < 1$ but non-negative everywhere else and positive on our intervals.

Answer (score 1):

The question only makes sense if $f(x)>0$ *only* in the given range. Then by continuity, $f(x)$ *must* be $0$ at $x=-4,-2,3,7$, and we take

$$f(x)=\pm(x+4)(x+2)(x-3)(x-7),$$ which is indeed a quartic polynomial.

The sign alternates between the roots so taking the $-$ sign fulfills the request.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure about "only makes sense".  Also $f(x)$ can be multiplied by any non-zero constant and still be correct.  .... But if we assume $f(x) > 0$ only on the range your answer and strategy is certainly the most straightforward and easiest solution to explain and/or achieve.

Comment: @fleablood: I avoided an arbitrary factor on purpose because the question is asking for "a" polynomial, and the emphasis is on the sign.

Comment: Well, like I said that strategy is certainly the most straightforward and easiest and clearly the intended answer.  In my answer though I fear giving the impression it is the only answer.

Comment: Ah, what I meant was "I fear giving the impression that $f(x)=-(x+4)(x+2)(x-3)(x-7)$ is the only answer so I felt obligated to address that in my answer".